# What is the method used by Pandas profiling tool to identify duplicates rows?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I'm looking for the rationale about the method used by pandas profiling tool to identify duplicates rows (in a dataframe with multiple columns)?
I couldn't find it in Pandas Profiling documentation.

Answer (score 0):

See [model/summary line 571-575](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/blob/4ab47b873225f8b1d11797024dd3f3c50c00a0c8/src/pandas_profiling/model/summary.py#L571).

In other cases, can be simplified as `sum(df.duplicated())`